# Why doesn't targetSdkVersion affect NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android, networking, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm writing an Android application targeting SDK version 10 (Android 2.3.3). It happens to do some networking in the main thread, which causes a NetworkOnMainThreadException on an Android 4.0 emulator. Now, I know it's wrong to do networking in the main thread, and I'll fix it, but the question is not about that.

I have a target SDK version set to 10 in my mainfest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

[Docs on the exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) say:

> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

So why the exception is thrown if it should not be in API 10?

Comment: are you using support library?

Comment: @user:145546 are you using support library?

Comment: I have an android-support-v4.jar in there. The main activity is android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity. Is that the support library you mean?

Comment: yes support library, it could be reason for exception that ur getting. Try a small test project with same target and same code but without support lib

Comment: Tried using android.app.Activity, it didn't help.

Comment: Are you testing it on a device/emulator with API > 10 ?